# What do these CSS definitions mean?

Tags: css

A website I was perusing had some CSS definitions that look liked this:

```
#intro, #code { ... }
#intro { ... }
#code { ... }
```

I've never seen this before.  Two questions:

1. In the first case, is it defining both `#intro` and `#code` with the
   same initial definition?
2. Are the subsequent definitions for `#intro` and `#code` additive to the original?

Comment: I think they are referring the "id"..
1) both intro and code get same styling
2) intro and code get specific styling additive to original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every page of code is read by the browser from top to bottom. What this means, is *that a latter statement overwrites a former.*

In the example you gave, this means that first `#intro` and `#code` get the same CSS after which they receive some extra CSS in their individual statements. These individual statements can have the same property (say, `width`) but the last statement will always be the one which will be used.

```
#intro, #code {width: 200px;}
#intro {width: 100px;} /* This value overwrites the previous */
```

**An exception** to this is when one statement is more specific than another. For example:

```
body #wrapper #intro, body #wrapper #intro #code {width: 200px;}
#intro {width: 100px;} /* This value is NOT as specific as or more specific than the previous, so it does NOT overwrite the previous value. */
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answers to direct questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes

;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both intro and code are getting same css

```
#intro { ... }
#code { ... }
```

each of them gets different css

Answer (score 1):

```
#intro, #code { ... } /* selects and styles both */
#intro { ... } /* selects only #intro and styles it */
#code { ... } /* selects only #code and styles it */
#intro #code { ... } /* this means that #code is child of #intro. Selects #code and styles it! */
```

and for your both questions answer is

### YES